# getHeight and getMeasuredHeight return 0, even in Runnable

Tags: java, android, return, runnable, measurement

So i was searching threw all the getHeight/widht problems-posts, and tried the different methods to solve the problem(like the globalLayoutListener, or Runnable) , to wait, till the FrameLayout has been created... but still my getHeight returns 0.
So this is my code right now:

```
private void zurechtruecken() {
    int n=1;

    spB =(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.spielbereich);

    spB.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            spielBh=spB.getMeasuredHeight();
            spielBb=spB.getMeasuredWidth();
        }
    });
```

This was my code with the GlobalLayoutListener:

```
private void zurechtruecken() {
    int i=24;
    int n=1;

    mView = findViewById(R.id.spielbereich);
    mView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener( 
        new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                mView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                spielBh=mView.getHeight();
                spielBb=mView.getWidth();
                Log.i("!",Integer.toString(spielBh));
                Log.i("!",Integer.toString(spielBb));


            }
        });
```

the "removeGlobalLayoutListener(this)" was crossed.(it was deprecated)

It could be important, that im measuring a Frame Layout

---

Thanks for any help!!
Botti560

Comment: is the visibility of the framelayout set to gone?

Comment: should it be? -its set to visible at the moment

Comment: have you tried using onFinishInflate()

Comment: no, visible is correct.

Comment: I am calling the method zurechtruecken, right after setContentView, in the onCreate, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too have had troubles like this before. If all else fails, extend FrameLayout in your own class and get the height/width values in the onMeasure method. Example:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

}
```

Easy to put it in you XML layout too with something like:

```
<com.yourdomain.yourappname.FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" > ...
```

Comment: Nice! I'll just try that

Comment: So you mean, that i should create another class, to measure the frameLayout?(Sorry, im quite new to programming)

Comment: Or could i just call the method zurechtruecken after onCreate?(but then also with runable?)

Comment: Yeah, you'd make a new class in which you extend FrameLayout. In it, you can have fields for height/width, and assign them, as shown, in onMeasure. As height/width are fields, you can get their values in your activity class. There may be an easier way, but if all else fails this works.

Comment: so i just tried to get the hight after everything was displayed mannualy(with onClick), but still, the height returned 0

Comment: Another method I've used is onWindowFocusedChanged in your Activity class:  @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {


  View layout = findViewById(R.id.yourFrameLayout);
  realHeight = layout.getHeight();

 }